# Statically defining data in store on store creation

Tags: extjs4

I want to create a simple store that can be reused containing only years.

```js
Ext.define('Workshop.store.YearsStore', 
{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    fields: ['id', 'type'],
    constructor: function(config) 
    {
        var years = [];
        for(var n=1972;n<=Ext.Date.format(new Date(), 'Y');n++)
        {
            years.push({id: n, type: n});
        }
        config.data = years;
        this.initConfig(config);
        return this;
    }
});
```

This does not work, how can I define a static set of data on store creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things to correct:

1. You do not need to call [`initConfig`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Base-method-initConfig). `initConfig` is intended to add getters & setters in the properties contained in the `config` properties in the class. In this case, you will just need to call `callParent`. It should take care the rest for you.
2. You forgot to take care of the case when `config` is not defined. `config` could be null, and your line `config.data` will raise `config is undefined` in some cases.
3. Use native `(new Date()).getFullYear()` seems to be better?

Below is the modified code, and [link to demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chaoszcat/K6HmC/).

```
Ext.define('Workshop.store.YearsStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    fields: ['id', 'type'],
    startYear: 1972,
    endYear: (new Date()).getFullYear(),
    constructor: function(cfg) {
        var me = this;

        //We init the configurations first (to copy startYear and endYear)
        Ext.apply(me, cfg || {});

        me.data = [];
        //Then we push data
        for(var n = me.startYear ; n <= me.endYear ; n++) {
            me.data.push({id: n, type: n});
        }

        //Then finally we callparent to init this store.
        me.callParent([cfg]);
    }
});
```